# MoviePy Output Video crazy distortion

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

Heyy guys, I just used MoviePy for the first time and at the beginning it worked totally fine. But then after the third clip (sec 34) I observed a weird disruption. I have no words for it but please take a look at it and the code below. Each of the clips is flawless as itself.  What could be the reason for it? Thanks in advance!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7aur2h6nej751p/my_tiktok_compilation.mp4?dl=0

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
import os, os.path


## Cutting the Clips ##
all_clips = []

# folder path
dir_path = r'./clips'
count = 0
# Iterate directory
for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
        count += 1
        clip = VideoFileClip(f"./clips/{path}")
        #clip.set_position("center") # automatically centered
        all_clips.append(clip)

print('File count:', count)

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(all_clips)
final_clip.write_videofile("my_tiktok_compilation.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate with `method` argument set to `compose`:

```
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(all_clips, method="compose")
```

From the docstring:

> method="compose", if the clips do not have the same resolution, the final
> resolution will be such that no clip has to be resized.
> As a consequence the final clip has the height of the highest clip and the
> width of the widest clip of the list. All the clips with smaller dimensions
> will appear centered. The border will be transparent if mask=True, else it
> will be of the color specified by `bg_color`.